# Can't get setSelectionRange to put the cursor at the beginning of the input

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
inputform.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
 const tgt = e.target;
 
 if (tgt.id==="usermsg") {
  if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey && tgt.value) {
    tgt.value = '';
    tgt.setSelectionRange(0,0);
  }
 }
});
```

As you hit ENTER its supposed to clear the textarea input and return the cursor to the start but it won't do it. Instead, the cursor stays at the second line. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xbc0vong/

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault();` to avoid default behavior.

Try this

```
inputform.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
 const tgt = e.target;
 
 if (tgt.id==="usermsg") {
  if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey && tgt.value) {
    e.preventDefault();
    tgt.value = '';
    tgt.setSelectionRange(0,0);
  }
 }
});
```

Code sandbox => https://jsfiddle.net/pa6cjweo/1/

Comment: @Cain Nuke, check this out!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a slight delay is needed after the `.value` attribute has been cleared. Using `setTimeout()` worked.

```js
const inputForm = document.forms[0];


inputForm.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id === 'userMsg' && e.keyCode === 13) {
    tgt.value = '';
    setTimeout(() => {
      tgt.focus();
      tgt.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="inputForm">
  <textarea id="userMsg"></textarea>
</form>
```